# Send form to mail via PHP, without page refresh and fields cleared

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I have a form on my website, which sends the information to my email via PHP code. It all works like a charm, though when I submit the form it refreshes/reloads the page.

Is there a way to make it so that when the user clicks the submit button that the page won't refresh and the fields will be cleared as well?

I've been finding many posts by people with the same problem here on SO, though it's not all working for me.

What I already tried: using an iFrame. The page then didn't refresh, and the fields wouldn't get cleared.

What's the best thing for me to do?

#### HTML:

```
                <form class="contact-form" action="form.php" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Naam" class="form-control" required>
                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" required>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Onderwerp" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Bericht..." id="message" rows="25" cols="10" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit">VERSTUUR BERICHT</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

#### PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$nam = $_POST["name"];
$ema = $_POST["email"];
$sub = $_POST["subject"];
$mes = $_POST["message"];

$your_email = "testertje777@gmail.com";
$subject = $sub;
$email_body = $mes;

if (isset($_REQUEST['message'])) {
    mail ($your_email, $subject, $email_body, "From: $nam <$ema>");
    header ("Location: bomatec.be");
    exit();
}
}
```

Comment: Learn JavaScript and about Ajax

Comment: [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) is the way to go, hand in hand with [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) :)

Comment: @TobiasF.Ideally you should link to better resources than W3Schools :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make it so that when the user clicks the submit button that the page won't refresh and the fields will be cleared as well?

There are multiple ways this can be achieved:

### iframe

Like you mentioned, an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) can be used as the target of the form. Ensure that the iframe has a *name* attribute defined, then use that value as the *target* value of the form.

```
<iframe name="ifr"></iframe>
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="form.php" target="ifr">
```

In order to have the form fields cleared with the form is submitted, use a JavaScript handler, like the one below. The `<script>` tag would be added to the `<body>` tag (though it could go in the `<head>` tag but that could slow down page load). When the DOM is ready, it will add a handler for form submission (using [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)). When the handler is called, the form fields will be cleared via the call to [HTMLFormElement.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.target.reset();
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that this code presumes there is only one form on the page. If there happen to be multiple then add an id attribute (e.g. `<form id="maiForm">`) and use that id attribute when accessing the form in JS (e.g. instead of `document.forms[0]` use `document.getElementById('mailForm')`).

See a demonstration of this technique in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gebn-4z60).

### AJAX (Javascript with XMLHttpRequest)

This is another technique similar to the iframe approach but instead it uses the Add a script tag like the one below to the `<body>` tag. It uses [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to wait for the DOM to be ready and then add an event handler for the form submission. That event handler will do the following:

- Prevent the default form submission with [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- Serialize the form data by instantiating an instance of [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)
- Send an asynchronous request using [XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) (i.e. AJAX) to the PHP page with the form data from the previous step as the POST data.
- Resets the form using [HTMLFormElement.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var formData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'form.php', true);
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xhr.readyState === 4) { //request is done
                  //request is finished - update DOM accordingly
              }
          }
          xhr.send(formData);
          document.forms[0].reset();
      });
  });
  </script>
  ```

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1qie-pjzb). Notice that *form.php* has been replaced by `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` because there can only be one page in that fiddle environment. Also the function [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is disabled there so the lines containing that function have been commented out (and the `l` replaced by a `1` since the code won't run otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by AJAX function, for example via JQuery:

```
$(".contact-form").submit(function() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
            alert("Thanks for your message!"),
            $("form.contact-form").each(function() {
            this.reset();
        });
        })
});
```

Also you can remove `action="form.php"` from you HTML code.
Please [check jsfiddle for full example](https://jsfiddle.net/geay84ez/).